# SQL echo output error through text input field

Tags: php, sql, ajax

i have written some sql code to output values from a database based on the first dropdown selection, but i can see the values being returned through inspect element in the console but my text field is blank

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
$sn = $_REQUEST['get_option'];
mysqli_select_db($connection, "dqa");
$result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM action_plan WHERE sn = '".$sn."' GROUP BY site");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  ?>
     <input  type="text" name="site"  value="<?php echo $row['site']; ?>">
  <?php
  }
mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

Comment: share your code

Comment: how many record database table action_plan  have ?

Comment: What does the generated html look like? And you should use a prepared statement to avoid sql injection and you should escape the values you output to html to avoid xss and breaking your html in general.

Comment: user3898470 not alot like 10 only

Comment: its a modal form box output, when i inspect element i can see the values being called through console but the text field is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
$sn = $_REQUEST['get_option'];
mysqli_select_db($connection, "dqa");
$result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM action_plan WHERE sn = '".$sn."' GROUP BY site");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
  {
  ?>
     <input  type="text" name="site[]"  value="<?php echo $row['site']; ?>" />
  <?php
  }
mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

Try to this added name="sites[]" to array and MYSQLI_ASSOC in getting result have association array Also added `< input '/'>`

for Select Drop Down :

```
    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
 $sn = $_REQUEST['get_option'];
 mysqli_select_db($connection, "dqa"); 
$result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM action_plan WHERE sn = '".$sn."' GROUP BY site"); ?> 
<select name="site" class="form-control" id="new_select">
 <?php
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
 ?> 
<option value="<?php echo $row['site']; ?>" ><?php echo $row['site']; ?> </option>
 <?php } ?> 
</select> 
<?php 
mysqli_free_result($result);
 mysqli_close($connection);  ?>
```

Comment: still the same thing, this is the output from when i inspect element i see the value being displayed <input type="text" name="site[]" value="Kawangware"> ,  and this is the input field in the modal form box  <input  type="text" name="site"  class="form-control" id="new_select">

Comment: share a screen shot with console for better understanding.

Comment: Use Select Box instead of input box , since input text inside/  input text is not supported.

updated my Answer @IsaiahAkello

Comment: Also remove it from other input filed.